# $("input").focus is not working

Tags: jquery, selector

I seem to be having a strange jQuery issue.  On my page I have a number of text fields and select boxes and this code:

```
$('input').focus(function() { alert($(this).attr("name")); });
```

(this is a placeholder code to be completed later on).  When the page loads, there are no errors.  However focusing any of the text inputs does nothing - at all.  I also tried selector `$(':input')` - with the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you're missing a `$(document).ready()` clause?

Comment: He said no errors on page though.

Comment: @John That wouldn't cause an error, it would just silently not bind any events.

Comment: Nothing. You're missing nothing. You have something wrong in another part of your code http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9ff26/1

Comment: Ahh, this is jQuery, not straight JS.  My bad.

Comment: Do you have any other javascript code that is running? If this is an external javascript file, it sounds like you forgot to link the file to your HTML page...

Comment: Perhaps they are `textarea`s?

Comment: i think you are missing something: `:input` http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: @Jack, `:input` matches `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: yep! that was it.  Long day...  If you put that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @zod - As I stated in my question, I tried this selector too - with the same result.

Comment: @Aleks, Sohnee's answer looks fine to me, you should accept it :)

Comment: Yes, it is - but you were first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a document ready block, to ensure the input you want to bind to is loaded before you try and add the event.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('input').focus( function() {
        alert($(this).attr("name")); 
    });
});
```